# tcpdf: adding multiple files to a zip directory with tcpdf

Tags: php, zend-framework2, tcpdf, php-7, fpdi

Using Tcpdf in with zend and not able to add files to zip
That's what i've tried

```
require_once('eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf.php');
$pageLayout = array(750, 800); 

$content=Array(
 '<html><body>Document A</body></html>',
 '<html><body>Document B</body></html>',
 '<html><body>Document C</body></html>'
);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "/tmp/final.zip";
$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($content as $i=>$html){
    $pdf =new TCPDF('P', 'pt', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output('/tmp/filename_' . $i . '.pdf', 'F');
    if(!file_exists('/tmp/filename_' . $i . '.pdf')){
        echo "File Doesn't Exist...";exit;
    }
    $zip->addFile('/tmp/filename_' . $i . '.pdf','filename_' . $i . '.pdf');
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="final.zip"');
readfile($filename);
```

Gives the error

> Warning: fopen(file:///tmp/filename_179367.pdf): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory ....

Comment: What line shows that error?

Comment: The line is of tcpdf

Comment: No such file or directory in ...\tecnickcom\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php on line 1854

Comment: Do you have write access to `/tmp/`? Does that directory exist?